# inserting new columns when not in a list using pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a spark df:

```
col1  col2     col3   col4
A      a1      null     s
A      a2      a2       g
A      null    a3       m
B      a2      a2       g
B      a3      a3       g
```

I want to insert new rows when BOTH col2 and col3 are missing elements from the list below:

```
list = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "b4", "c7"]
```

Since in this example both col2 and col3 are missing b4 and c7, i should have the following:

```
col1  col2     col3   col4
A      a1      null     s
A      a2      a2       g
A      null    a3       m
B      a2      a2       g
B      a3      a3       g

A      b4      b4       k
A      c7      c7       k
B      b4      b4       k
B      c7      c7       k
```

The last 4 rows is what i want to add (this is an example but the actual df is bigger). 
Any thoughts of how this may be coded???

Comment: where does k come from in col4 for the last 4 rows? or is it just a constant we should add ? also, shouldnt there also be a row added for B with col2 and col3 as a1

Comment: Mohammad Murtaza Hashmi yes you are exactly right - just a constant to add plus a row for B for a1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, using **`window functions`** and  **`explode`** logic(**`spark2.4+`**):

```
df.show() #sample dataframe

#+----+----+----+----+
#|col1|col2|col3|col4|
#+----+----+----+----+
#|   A|  a1|null|   s|
#|   A|  a2|  a2|   g|
#|   A|null|  a3|   m|
#|   B|  a2|  a2|   g|
#|   B|  a3|  a3|   g|
#+----+----+----+----+

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w=Window().partitionBy("col1")
w1=Window().partitionBy("col1").orderBy(F.lit(1))

df\
  .withColumn("col1_2",F.flatten(F.collect_list(F.array("col2","col3")).over(w)))\
  .withColumn("list", F.array(*[F.lit(x) for x in list]))\
  .withColumn("except",F.array_except("list","col1_2"))\
  .withColumn("rowNum", F.row_number().over(w1))\
  .withColumn("max",F.max("rowNum").over(w))\
  .withColumn("col2", F.when(F.col("rowNum")==F.col("max"), F.array_union(F.array("col2"),F.col("except")))\
                       .otherwise(F.array(F.col("col2"))))\
  .withColumn("col3", F.when(F.col("rowNum")==F.col("max"),F.array_union(F.array("col3"),F.col("except")))\
                       .otherwise(F.array(F.col("col3")))).select(*[x for x in df.columns])\
  .withColumn("col5", F.when(F.size("col2")>1, F.expr("""array_repeat('k',size(col2)-1)"""))\
                           .otherwise(F.array("col4")))\
  .withColumn("col4", F.when(F.size("col2")>1,F.flatten(F.array(F.array("col4"),"col5")))\
                         .otherwise(F.array("col4"))).drop("col5")\
  .withColumn("zipped", F.explode(F.arrays_zip("col2","col3","col4")))\
  .select("col1","zipped.*")\
  .show()

#+----+----+----+----+
#|col1|col2|col3|col4|
#+----+----+----+----+
#|   B|  a2|  a2|   g|
#|   B|  a3|  a3|   g|
#|   B|  a1|  a1|   k|
#|   B|  b4|  b4|   k|
#|   B|  c7|  c7|   k|
#|   A|  a1|null|   s|
#|   A|  a2|  a2|   g|
#|   A|null|  a3|   m|
#|   A|  b4|  b4|   k|
#|   A|  c7|  c7|   k|
#+----+----+----+----+
```